# How to append options from select box no matter if option is selected or not

Tags: jquery, html

I want to know how to append options from a select box into another select box. But the catch is that I want to append all students that are in the select box without caring if the option is selected or not, if the student is in the select box then they should be appended into the other select box.

Below is the jquery code I have which is suppose to do the appended but is not happening at moment:

```
var selectedStudents = jQuery("select#studentadd").find("option");
selectedStudents.appendTo($("select#studentexist"));
```

Below is the select box `#studentadd`:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="addtextarea" id="studentadd" size="10">
    <option value='1'>u08743 - Joe Cann</option>
    <option value='4'>u03043 - Jill Sanderson</option>
    <option value='7'>u08343 - Craig Moon</option>
</select>
```

Below is the select box the students should be appended into:

```
<select id="studentexist" name="existtextarea"></select>
```

Comment: do you just need a foreach?

Comment: I do not want to copy it to other select box, I do want to physically take it out from first box and place it into second box

Comment: did it not work with document.ready?

Comment: @Anton, No the append works without document ready, what I realised was that if I have one option highlighted, then it will perform the append, but if I have no options selected or more than one option selected, then it does not perform the append

Comment: Look, this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2V53n/1/) works, whether you select something or not. So I guess your problem is somewhere else. Could you post your entire jQuery code?

Comment: @Aioros I included a fiddle which contains most of my code  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9vLn/4)  . Do you want me to paste full code in question? Full code contains ajacx linking to php script so I havn't inclded this in fiddle. But you can see it doesn't work in fiddle even though code is similar to yours in your working fiddle

Comment: I answered your comment there, and the fiddle is enough, but I think you should update your question: right now is quite difficult to gather all information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$("select#studentadd option").each(function(){
    $("select#studentexist").append($(this).clone());
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksrpX/).

**Update:** (instead of copy)

```
$("select#studentadd option").each(function(){
    $("select#studentexist").append($(this));
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksrpX/1/).

Comment: please look at my comments below question

Comment: I havnt got clone() in my code, my code is still the same in the question

Comment: @Manixman, you want to move out all options from `select#studentadd` to `select#studentexist`, right ? [it's working here](http://jsfiddle.net/ksrpX/1/).

Comment: Not working in my app when I tried this, I selected multiple options and it didn't append any option to the other select box

Comment: It is stil only working if one option is select, let me try and create a fiddle with what I hav at moment

Comment: @Manixman, It's working in the fiddle without any selected option.

Comment: Yeah but not working in my application, this is my fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9vLn/4/

Comment: Ok thanks to something altered in php (I use ajax in my app which you don't see in fiddle), by changing it around a bit and implementing your code, it allows multiple select options to be appended to other select box, now just need to know why non select options don't append in my jsfiddle example but it works in yours

Comment: You had quite a few errors in your fiddle. I modified it and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9vLn/5/

Comment: @Aioros The problem is that they are not errors in my application coz I have them class and I need the empty to empty the select box. Look my code has ajax and php so I can't show it in fiddle but here is a demo app which is exactly same as my main app, have a look at the app and you will be able to see what is happening, try and submit students when selected and unselected and you can see what is happening [app](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/InputTest.php)

Comment: @SheikhHeera Have a look at comment above as well

Comment: Look, your fiddle used $('select#studentselect').append(), when the select id was actually "studentexist". If you change just that single thing, it works.

Comment: @Aioros It is suppose to be #studentselect, I messed up on the paste stating it was studentexist but it is studentselect not studentexist

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
    var str="";
        $('#studentadd').find('option').each(function(){
        str+="<option>"+$(this).html()+"</option>";
        });
$('#studentadd').html("");
        $('#studentexist').html(str);
```

Comment: please look at my comments below question

Comment: ok i got your comment @Manixman Please see my answer i have change it to what you want

Comment: tried your code but did not work, did not append anything. At moment my code now appends one or more selected options (something sorted in php allowed multiple select options), but just none options don't get appended as well

Comment: When do you want to append after selection of any option within select box or directly without selection from one select box to another select box.

Comment: I have included a fiddle here to show you what Im doing, http://jsfiddle.net/Z9vLn/4/, I want it to append after a button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

It should work, maybe you forgot this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selectedStudents = jQuery("select#studentadd").find("option");
            selectedStudents.appendTo($("select#studentexist"));
});
```

Comment: please look at my comments below question

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jquery` [$.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to do this

```
var opt = $("#studentadd").html();
$("#studentexist").html(opt);
```

update:

Use [$.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to move DOM

```
var opt = $("#studentadd").detach();
$("#studentexist").html(opt);
```

Comment: please look at my comments below question

Comment: tried your code but did not work, did not append anything. At moment my code now appends one or more selected options (something sorted in php allowed multiple select options), but just none options don't get appended as well

Answer (score 0):

Your code works flawlessy, actually, but it moves the options from the first select to the second. If you wanted to copy them, you would need to add a `.clone()` ([here for a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2V53n/)):

```
var selectedStudents = jQuery("select#studentadd").find("option");
selectedStudents.clone().appendTo($("select#studentexist"));
```

Comment: please look at my comments below question

Answer (score 0):

use `.clone()`: http://jsbin.com/ucozis/4/edit

```
$(function(){

    $('#studentexist').html($('#studentadd option').clone());
    $('#studentadd').html('');

});
```

just after `.append()` or `.clone()` blank the select.

As you mentioned your scenario this is the updated answer to that:

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#studentexist').html($('#studentadd option').clone());
    $('#studentadd').html('');
  });
});
```

and here is the fiddle which replaces all the contents on click of the button
http://jsbin.com/ucozis/5/edit

Comment: please look at my comments below question

Comment: It is a multi select box, with size of 10, it is done on a button click, user clicks on a button and what I want is all of the options in the select box to append to the other select box